# Is there a way to force Craft to notice a new license key?

Tags: license

We are rebuilding a site from scratch using the existing license key (same domain) for the new Craft install. The new install was initially running as a Pro Trial, but Craft isn't seeing that we've added the new license. Not a huge problem, I'm sure it'll notice when there's an update or new environment, but just wondered if there is a way to 'refresh' the license.

Comment: Try clearing the Craft `storage/runtime/cache` folder. Licensing info is stored for 24 hours at a time, so it's likely you're looking at stale data.

Comment: This worked, thanks Brad

Comment: Want to add that as an official answer, Jake?

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the Craft storage/runtime/cache folder will force the license refresh.

Licensing info is stored for 24 hours at a time.

It's also worth double-checking that you definitely have the correct license installed in /config/license.key and specify the correct domain in your Craft ID account.